# Como trabalhar com tipos de dados array do PostgreSQL usando Hibernate

Tags: java, array, hibernate, postgresql

Como realizar a recuperação e salvamento de objetos usando colunas do tipo `array` usando o `Hibernate`? No meu caso quero salvar `String`. Como defino no `model` o objeto? Achei na net [alguns exemplos](http://finethinking.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/hibernate-arrays-and-postgres/) mas não funcionaram.

Minha classe `userType` extende de outra, por isso não implementa todos o métodos.

```
public class ArrayStringType extends TypeHibernate {

    public static final String TYPE = "arrayStringType";

    public Class<String[]> returnedClass() {
        return String[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor sessionImpl, Object obj) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
        return NullUtil.isNull(array) ? null : (String[]) array.getArray(); 
   }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor sessionImpl) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        Connection connection = st.getConnection();
        String[] stringArray = (String[]) value;

        if (NullUtil.isNull(stringArray)) {
            st.setNull(index, CharArrayType.INSTANCE.sqlType());            
        } else {            
            Array array = connection.createArrayOf("char", stringArray);
            st.setArray(index, array);      
        }

    }

}
```

Tipo da coluna e seu nome no banco

```
ufsinss character(2)[]
```

Versão do JDBC

```
postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41
```

Tem apresentado erro na parte do `nullSafeSet`.

```
EDIT 1:
```

Após Googlear um pouco, achei o seguinte. O tipo nessa linha estava errado, foi alteado para, `Array array = connection.createArrayOf("bpchar", stringArray);`. Descobri olhando no `SO.com`. Através de buscar pelo array no `nullSafeGet` usando essa linha `array.getBaseTypeName();`. Meu problema agora é o `nullSet`, quando o vetor vier nulo.

```
EDIT 2:
```

Por fim o que faltava era colocar este código para quando o `array` vier nulo. `st.setNull(index, Types.ARRAY);`

Abaixo vou postar a resposta com a descrição da ideia. Favor que precisar e ser ajudado dar um up vote na minha resposta.

Comment: Não entendi nada.. Poderia explicar melhor? Poste o código das suas tentativas aqui ao invés de postar links.

Comment: @Math o código é o mesmo do site. O que quero fazer é o seguinte, no `postgres` você pode definir um campo do tipo `vetor` no meu caso esta definido como `vetor` de `String`. Nativamente o `Hibernate` não possui suporte, queria saber como fazer isso. Vi que é possível usando `UserType` mas o meu da erro.

Comment: Não me parece uma boa opção, em JPA (que abstrai o Hibernate por exemplo) se você definir o relacionamento pode usar um atributo multivalorado (array, List, etc...) e ele vai gerar várias linhas na outra tabela, assim você fica mais livre.

Comment: @prmottajr mas gostaria de utilizar deste modo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21984484/1792268) resposta do SO em inglês é bem o que você precisa.

Uma tradução seria:

---

> Eu tentei algumas versões baseadas no Tipo Array intruduzidas pelo JDBC4: [How can I set a String[] parameter to a native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042181/how-can-i-set-a-string-parameter-to-a-native-query). O problem é que o Hibernate ( pelo menos na versão 4.3.1.final) não funciona com esta nova funcionalidade e me retornou uma mensagem de erro.

```
Could not determine a type for class: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
```

> Então eu tive que fazer um UserType específico (baseado em varios artigos do stackoverflow, e outras fontes)
>
> Meu Model

```
@Type(type = "fr.mycompany.dao.hibernate.types.ArrayUserType")
private String[] values;
```

> Meu UserType

```
public class ArrayUserType implements UserType {

    /** Constante contenant le type SQL "Array".
     */
    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

    /**
     * Return the SQL type codes for the columns mapped by this type. The
     * codes are defined on <tt>java.sql.Types</tt>.
     * 
     * @return int[] the typecodes
     * @see java.sql.Types
     */
    public final int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    /**
     * The class returned by <tt>nullSafeGet()</tt>.
     * 
     * @return Class
     */
    public final Class returnedClass() {
        return String[].class;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from a JDBC resultset. Implementors
     * should handle possibility of null values.
     * 
     * @param resultSet a JDBC result set.
     * @param names the column names.
     * @param session SQL en cours.
     * @param owner the containing entity 
     * @return Object
     * @throws org.hibernate.HibernateException exception levée par Hibernate
     * lors de la récupération des données.
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException exception SQL 
     * levées lors de la récupération des données.
     */
    @Override
    public final Object nullSafeGet(
            final ResultSet resultSet, 
            final String[] names, 
            final SessionImplementor session, 
            final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }

        String[] array = (String[]) resultSet.getArray(names[0]).getArray();
        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement. Implementors
     * should handle possibility of null values. A multi-column type should be written
     * to parameters starting from <tt>index</tt>.
     * 
     * @param statement a JDBC prepared statement.
     * @param value the object to write
     * @param index statement parameter index
     * @param session sql en cours
     * @throws org.hibernate.HibernateException exception levée par Hibernate
     * lors de la récupération des données.
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException exception SQL 
     * levées lors de la récupération des données.
     */
    @Override
    public final void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object value, 
            final int index, final SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        if (value == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
        } else {
            String[] castObject = (String[]) value;
            Array array = session.connection().createArrayOf("text", castObject);
            statement.setArray(index, array);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public final Object assemble(final Serializable arg0, final Object arg1)
            throws HibernateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final Serializable disassemble(final Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        } else if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return x.equals(y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode(final Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public final Object replace(
        final Object original,
        final Object target,
        final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
 }
```

> E no final, mas não menos importante, quando eu preciso rodar Queries Nativas de SQL, eu tenho que foçar o tipo do parametro com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
String[] values = ...
Type arrayType = new CustomType(new ArrayUserType());
query.setParameter("value", values, arrayType);
```

---

Comment: Estou validando sua resposta cara! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, gostaria de agradecer ao usuário acima que me postou a resposta, pois eu havia alguns dias trabalhando nesta solução para a empresa onde trabalho. Primeiro estava eu utilizando meu caso banco de dados `postgres`, e umas das tabelas estavam demarcadas com o tipo de dado `char[2]`. Isto mesmo, um vetor de `char` com tamanho 2. A primeira coisa foi procurar um algo relacionado e encontrei que o `Hibernate` não possui suporte nativo, então seria necessário fazer um `converter`. Neste caso usando a classe que estou postando já faz implementação da `UserType`, onde era apenas necessário implementar os métodos `nullSafeGet` e `nullSafeSet` além `returnedClass`.

Então primeiramente implementamos o `nullSafeGet` que busca o objeto do banco de dados.

```
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor sessionImpl, Object obj) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);        
        return NullUtil.isNull(array) ? null : (String[]) array.getArray(); 
   }
```

A primeira linha pega o objeto e atribui a um `array` da classe `java.sql.array`. Chamo a atenção para a possibilidade deste modo de se descobrir qual tipo de dado o `Hibernate` trabalha da sua coluna para ser utilizado no `nullSafeSet`. Deste modo o usuário irá ter um retorno do tipo na String, somente para teste, lembrando que a coluna deve ter algum valor preenchido pois, se não possuir vai gerar uma `nullPointerException`.

```
String tipoDaColuna = array.getBaseTypeName();
```

O tipo retornado foi `bpchar`, então partimos para implementar o método `nullSafeSet`.

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor sessionImpl) throws HibernateException, SQLException {    

    Connection connection = st.getConnection();
    String[] stringArray = (String[]) value;

    if (NullUtil.isNull(stringArray)) {
        st.setNull(index, Types.ARRAY);
    } else {            
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("bpchar", stringArray);
        st.setArray(index, array);      
    }
}
```

Este método acima busca o vetor, caso esteja nulo, eu seto a coluna como `null` do tipo `array`, caso contrário seto no objeto o vetor conforme podem ver acima.

O tipo de dado no model esta como `String[] ufs`.

As chamadas de bibliotecas foram.

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
```

É isso, obrigado!